# Increasing tomcat session id increases security

Tags: session-management

Tomcat gives a configuration **sessionIdLength** to be configurable, but does increasing the session id increases its security or its just security through obscurity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It increases the difficulty of brute-force guessing session identifiers. This only increases security in general if session guessing is a realistic attack.

The default value of `16` (128 bits) is pretty standard across web frameworks and already makes brute-force guessing very difficult. See [OWASP's justification](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Insufficient_Session-ID_Length) for this length.

Unless you have conditions that are different from the average web app (for example if you have a very large number S of simultaneously active guessable sessions), it is unlikely you'll get any benefit from increasing the length of the session ID beyond 128 bits.

(On the other hand, it doesn't cost you much either.)